# how to select exact values from 5 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello guys this my first Q in stackoverflow so i'll be clear with you i'm very new to php so take it easy on me .
right so what am trying to do is i have 5 tables where's the relation have already been set
 and i'm trying to show the related categorys and platforms using the game id note that the category has a table on it own and so as the platform then there's two other tables which have the game id and the cat id together and same as for the platform and the game and the field i have in the games table are:
id-->for the game id 
name-->for the name of the game
details and image.
and in the game_cat:
g_id and cat_id
then thers the table for the category which has the name and id 
and the same for the platform . these are my tables which i'm trying to select from 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TyS7.jpg)
and my sql is:

```
SELECT games.*,
    game_cat.*,
    category.*
FROM games,
    game_cat,
    category
WHERE games.id='game_cat.g_id'
AND game_cat.g_id='game_cat.cat_id'
AND game_cat.cat_id='category.id'
```

but it doesn't work on phpmyadmin sql so I've done some research and there's something called join in sql which i'm not familiar with.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not meaning to be unkind, but your question is very hard to read - some basic punctuation and formatting (paragraph breaks, code blocks, etc.) would go a long way to helping. As it stands, your question is almost impossible to understand so it's very hard to help you.

Comment: Look at this as a starting point https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Comment: You've seen https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html? For future posting see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Using coma to separate the tables is equivalent of inner join. You should read more for sql queries before ask questions here. More info you can read from https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: @bksi Not by itself - it could also return the Cartesian product of the tables, if no WHERE was specified.

Comment: that query alone should be throwing you an error, in using single quotes around table/column names

Comment: Ok sorry for my spelling, punctuation and formatting i"m not a native speaker but you are right and thanks for the quick reply i'll try to improve how i ask next time . and i have tried to added a picture but it doesn't show up i don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use single quotes for column  name (when need  use eventually backtics)
Use inner join  if you have alway columns match (otherwise you left join ) and you can use alias for a compact query
(i have added  also the last two tables ...hope the related columns name are right)

```
SELECT g.*,gc.*,c.* , gp.*, p.*
FROM games g
INNER JOIN  game_cat gc on  g.id = gc.g_id
INNER JOIN  category c on gc.cat_id=c.id
INNER JOIN  game_platform gp on  g.id = gp.g_id
INNER JOIN  platform p on gp.paltform_id=p.id
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to JOIN between the tables based on the foreign-key relationship between them (if you don't know what this is, go read up on it!). Something like this (I don't know what columns represent the foreign keys, so making this up):

```
SELECT games.*,
    game_cat.*,
    category.*
FROM games g
  INNER JOIN game_cat gc on (g.game_id = gc.g_id)
  INNER JOIN category c on (gc.cat_id = c.cat_id)
WHERE games.id='game_cat.g_id'
AND game_cat.g_id='game_cat.cat_id'
AND game_cat.cat_id='category.id';
```

This looks like a standard implementation of a many-to-many relationship between `games` and `category` - would that be correct?

Comment: Your query will return the exact same result as OP's query

Comment: @bksi Yes, but he said he didn't understand JOIN, hence my answer.

Comment: i don't have many to many relationship because i have a table for game_cat which have unique columns for the game with the category id   so it wont repeat